# How to add data of different items?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi guys I have a problem. I need to add the price of different items but I don't know how?. I am using Firebase and Android Studio.

I have the next database structure:

```
a/myCart
    a
       --- name: Pizza
       ---price: 5
       ---image: https://im...

    b
       ---name: Soup
       ---price: 12
       ---image: https://im...
```

I need to show in a TextView the total of my Cart, in this example: $17.00

I am using Firebase UI.

My code is like :

```
public class Cart extends AppCompatActivity {
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<MyData, myViewHolder3> adapter = null;
    int total;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart);

/////I need to show the total here

        final TextView txtTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total);

        RecyclerView r = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.listaCart);
        final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        final String user = "a";
        final DatabaseReference myRef1 = database.getReference("users/"+user+"/myCart");

        r.setHasFixedSize(true);

        ////
        StaggeredGridLayoutManager layoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(1, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        r.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

           adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<MyData, myViewHolder3>(
                MyData.class, R.layout.cart_list, myViewHolder3.class, myRef1
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(final myViewHolder3 viewHolder, final MyData s, final int position) {
                // 

          final String key = adapter.getRef(position).getKey();

            viewHolder.setPrice(["$"+price+".00");


            viewHolder.setName(s.getName());
            viewHolder.setImageProduct(s.getImage());

            }
        };
        r.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

This is part of my Cart Activity, please help me!

Comment: What is the problem / stopper exactly?

Comment: Where is the method returning the data from firebase, Because you know you must have one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the `myCart` node is a direct child of your Firebase root and the `price` property is of type Integer, to sum all those prices, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference myCartRef = rootRef.child("myCart");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        int total = 0
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            int price = ds.child("price").getValue(Integer.class);
            total = total + price;
        }
        Log.d("TAG", "total = " + total);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
myCartRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output will be: `total = 17`